# Sending mails via php and it reflects in the owners sent items

Tags: php, sendmail

When sending a email via php i want it to appear in my outlooks sent items.
I have tried imap_send but it does not reflect in the sent items. Is this possible. Thanks

### edit

i used imap_append to solve achieve this.

imap_append($connection, "{mail.example.com/novalidate-cert}INBOX.Sent")

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I know for 100% sure this is possible is by sending through an Exchange account. That way, Exchange will sync the sent items folder on an Outlook client.

If your PHP instance is on the same machine as the Outlook instance, [this may be what you're looking for](http://aaronsaray.com/blog/2007/07/06/send-e-mail-from-outlook-using-php/) - although I haven't tried it so I don't know if it works.

If your PHP instance is not on the same machine as Outlook and you don't use Exchange, you're scuppered.

**EDIT**

It may be possible to do this with IMAP, [as long as you configure Outlook correctly](http://www.hosting.com/support/email/synchronize-sent-items-in-microsoft-outlook-with-imap), but it would also depend on the mail server keeping a local sent items folder and handling mail sent through it correctly, which it may not.

Comment: Thanks for your help. My question was not clear enough sorry. I wanted to save the mail on the servers mailbox. I used imap_append to do this